# Geolocation using hostip with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery, geolocation, cross-domain

This is probably a very silly question. I am trying to do a geolocation to find a users address based on their ip address using the api provided by http://www.hostip.info/use.html. I am using this in conjuction with jquery with the following code:

```
$.get("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Sadly, this doesn't seem to work. The alert is never triggered so i assume the call never returns. Has anyone done this before? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the call to them is successful.  Cross-domain limitations are likely to prevent you from reading the result data.  If hostip offered a [JSONP API](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/), that would be usable, but I didn't see any mention of one on their site.

Comment: Well [hostip offers a JSON API](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) and it supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but some browsers including Internet Explorer 9 don't support CORS.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Google's AJAX API, then it's really easy to get location using their [Client Location](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation) functionality -- this doesn't require any cross-domain calls.

```
if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
    var lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
    var lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
    ...
```

Otherwise, as others have pointed out, you'll need a service that provides JSONP or you'll need to write a proxy on your own server to get the data for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make cross-domain calls for XML data.  Other sites offer a JSON interface:

```
http://ipinfodb.com/ip_query.php?ip=999.999.999.999&output=json
```

which you can cross-domain call using the [YUI GET Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/get/) or via JQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You can't make calls to foreign domains from javascript. This is definitely the problem. You either need to set up a proxy script on your server that fetches remote pages for you, or find a service than implements JSONP as mentioned above.

Comment: You can now make calls to foreign domains from JavaScript using modern browsers. Most of them support `CORS` and `http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php` also supports `CORS`.